# Why won't this dynamically-generated <div> display?

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

Okay, so on my website I have a slider thingy, where it um "slides" between things, and on the homepage, when the page loads it checks the database to see if Column discounts has a value of 1 (or greater than 0, to be precise), which means that if($discounts>0){//do something;} so, if the value inside the discount column is greater than 0, it will (SHOULD) display a dynamically created DIV saying something like "Yay we have discounts" etc.

But, it won't display! It only displays 2 slides. But the value in the DB is set to 1, so it should be displaying the 3rd slide!

Inside the Head:

```
if($ddiscount >0)
{           
    $outputsy = '<div class="ambitios_slide">

                     <div class="clear"> 

                         <h1 class="ambitios_fleft">'.$dimage.'</h1>

                         <div class="ambitios_sleder_title">'.$dtitle.'</div>

                         <p>'.$ddescription.'</p>

                     </div>

                  </div>';
 }
 else
 {
     $outputsy = null;
 }
```

Inside the body:

```
<?php if($outputsy != null) {echo $outputsy;} ?>
```

There are no warnings, no errors. The webpage loads fine. It just never displays the dynamically generated DIV! Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong here?

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: `if($ddiscount >0)` did you mean `if($discount >0)`

Comment: Does the code make it to the output? if so, does firebug/inspector show anything regarding css display/visibility? Otherwise, output/echo some variables tracing it down to the failing portion.

Comment: @Kyle the others have a 'd' prepended, so probs not.

Comment: Nup. The reason there's a d infront of discount ($ddiscount) is because I have other variables like $amount and $title, used for different things, so I have all variables related to the discount part of the page begin with a d (including the discount variable itself). :) - But thanks for checking!

Comment: the `if` is inside of one `for` or `foreach`?

Comment: Ahh, the example text has "which means that if($discounts>0){//do something;}" ... I'm still thinking...

Comment: Have you tried a echo($ddiscount) before your if statement to ensure that its value is returning from your database greater than 0 as expected?

Comment: this is working ..!! what result do you expect?

Comment: I think you forgot to concatenate the strings... `$outputsy.= 'text';` and.. instead of null, put `$outputsy.= '';`;

Comment: Thank you all, I have var_dumped and echo'd/print_r'd and $ddiscount comes back with NULL. Before I was just echoe-ing, an =d it didn't even display NULL, but var_dump(); worked. Now, I just need to figure out why it's null. I'm guessing it's got something to do with my mysql thing

Comment: Got it! I have 2 mysql queries, one for the discounts, and another for authentication of users. In the discounts part where I have: *while($va = mysql_fetch_array($discounts))..* I forgot to change $auth to $discounts. Thanks all for your help! :)

Comment: @Joseadrian; How come we have to use .= instead of =? I've never seen that, unless we are adding to something, instead of just assigning (which is what I'm doing)?

Comment: also, in the future before asking a question on stackoverflow, please take care to do some basic debugging. In this question we have zero idea what actually went wrong (based on your comment two above this one, i still have no idea what you're talking about...$auth...?) all we did was tell you how to debug and you figured it out yourself.

Comment: I debugged before I came here, but for some reason print_r($ddiscount); didn't show anything, and echo $ddiscount; didn't show anything. It wasn't until when you told me to use var_dump(); instead, and that's what helped me figure the rest out. Before posting this question I had no idea var_dump even existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `else` part, try setting `$outputsy` to some random string and see if that gets outputted.

Also try doing a `var_dump($ddiscount);` and seeing what the actual value of `$ddiscount` is. If it's something other than what is expected, the problem may be something before this code.

Comment: Thanks, contagious! I var_dump();'d and it said NULL. Yay, now i can sort of see where it may be going wrong because there's only one other thing (mysql script)